# Track how much network data my Android app uses

Tags: performance, android-studio

In Android Studio 1.4 they've introuced a Network Monitor. This is great, but it only shows real time data.

Is there any way to see how much data is being used overall, or am I limited to watching only real time performance?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to code? Or for a tool to see the stats?

Comment: Just a tool to see the stats. Android Studio only shows network traffic in real time, but doesn't accumulate the traffic.